# Monorepo: lerna run --scope vs yarn workspace

Tags: yarnpkg, monorepo, lerna

Monorepo project using lerna and yarn workspaces.

What is the difference between `lerna run --scope <package-name> <command>` and `yarn workspace <package-name> <command>`?

Which one should i use?

Comment: There is not much difference between the two. Both will run the command/script in given workspace. Lerna is just another tool and you might not need it if you are already using yarn workspaces.